# Test changing router from service

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have an Angular application version 8 and I have a service that is able to change the router like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RoutingService implements OnDestroy {

  constructor(
    private router: Router) {}

  public changeRoute(selectRoute1: string, selectRoute2: string): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/' + selectRoute1 + '/' + selectRoute2]);
    return;
  }
```

The services properly works.

I have to create a test case with Jasmine and Karma (but it doesn't work):

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { async, fakeAsync, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbDatepickerModule, NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { Store, StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';

describe('Routing Service', () => {
  let routingService: RoutingService;
  let router: Router;
  let store: Store<any>;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        NgbDatepickerModule,
        NgbModule,
        DfModule,
        NgSelectModule,
        NgOptionHighlightModule,
        FormsModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot({}),
        StoreModule.forFeature('scope', scopeReducer),
        EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        NgSelectModule
      ],
      providers: [{
          provide: Router,
          useValue: {
            routerState: {
              snapshot : {
                url :  '/h1/h2'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      declarations: [AppComponent, FoxComponent],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    routingService = TestBed.get(RoutingService);
    store = TestBed.get(Store);
  });


  it('should change the route', fakeAsync(() => {
    const navigateSpy = spyOn(router);
    routingService.changeRoute('fox', 'tango);
    window.setTimeout(function waitAgainForCloseCallback() {

      expect(navigateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/fox/tango'])
    }, 10);
  }));
});
```

But it doesn't work. Have you some idea in order to fix it or to write another unit test?

Answer (score 0):

What's the error you get?

Try this:

```
it('should change the route', fakeAsync(() => {
    // add this line
    router = TestBed.get(Router);
    // change this line
    const navigateSpy = spyOn(router, 'navigate');
    routingService.changeRoute('fox', 'tango);
    expect(navigateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/fox/tango'])
  }));
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The console says me:   Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for navigate()
 on this line:  const navigateSpy = spyOn(router, 'navigate');